# Как залить файл (картинку/фото) на php сервер с vue клиента

Tags: php, vue.js

Вот мой клиент

```
<script>
  import Axios from 'axios'
  /* eslint-disable */
  export default {
    name: 'Home',
    metaInfo: {
      title: 'My Awesome Webapp',
      // override the parent template and just use the above title only
      titleTemplate: null
    },
    data() {
      return {
        url1: null,
        url: [],
        form: false,
        snackbar: false,
        claim: {
          fio: '',
          place: '',
          phone: '',
          email: '',
          numbers: '',
          cords: '',
          upFiles: [],
        },
        message: '',
        rules: {
          general: [(value) => !!value || 'Це поле обовязкове'],
          email: [value => {
            if (!!value) {
              return /^\w+([.-]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(value) || 'Введите верный email'
            } else {
              return 'Це поле обовязкове'
            }
          }],
          phone: [value => {
            if (!!value) {
              return value.length > 9 || 'Введите верный номер телефона'
            } else {
              return 'Це поле обовязкове'
            }
          }],
          fio: [value => {
            if (!!value) {
              return /[А-Яа-яЁёІіЇїЄє]+$/.test(value) || 'Введите верный fio'
            } else {
              return 'Це поле обовязкове'
            }
          }],
          numbers: [value => {
            if (!!value) {
              return /[А-Я]{2}[0-9]{4}[А-Я]{2}/.test(value) || 'Введите верно номер авто'
            } else {
              return 'Це поле обовязкове'
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      send() {
        if (!!this.claim.fio && !!this.claim.place && !!this.claim.phone && !!this.claim.email && !!this.claim.numbers &&
          !!this.claim.cords) {
            Axios.post(`http://skarga.gopua.loc/claim/create`, this.claim,{ 
                        headers: { 
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' 
                        } 
                    } )

            .then(({
              data: {
                token
              }
            }) => {
              // if (redirect) router.push(redirect)
            }).catch(({
              response: {
                data
              }
            }) => {
              this.snackbar = true
              this.message = data.message
            })
        } else {
          this.snackbar = true
          this.message = 'Заполните все поля'
        }
      },
      addFile() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.$refs.file.files.length; i++) {
          this.url.push(URL.createObjectURL(this.$refs.file.files[i]))
          this.claim.upFiles.push(this.$refs.file.files[i])
        }
      },
    },

  }
</script>
```

и файл приходит мне в таком виде

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (0) {
  }
}
```

при том, что  `console.log(this.claim.upFiles);`

показывает мне нормальный файл 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Снова отвечаю сам же на свой вопрос. 
Вот такой скрипт у меня получился. 
Данные по итпу fio, place приходят в $_POST, а файлы в $_FILES.

```
if (!!this.claim.fio && !!this.claim.place && !!this.claim.phone && !!this.claim.email && !!this.claim.numbers &&
  !!this.claim.cords) {

  var data = new FormData();
  data.append('fio', this.claim.fio)
  data.append('place', this.claim.place)
  data.append('phone', this.claim.phone)
  data.append('email', this.claim.email)
  data.append('numbers', this.claim.numbers)
  data.append('cords', this.claim.cords)

  for (var i = 0; i< this.claim.upFiles.length;i++){
    data.append('file['+i+']', this.claim.upFiles[i])
  }

  Axios.post(`http://loc.gopua.xyz/claim/create`, data)

    .then(({
      data: {
        token
      }
    }) => {
      // if (redirect) router.push(redirect)
    }).catch(({
      response: {
        data
      }
    }) => {
      this.snackbar = true
      this.message = data.message
    })
} else {
  this.snackbar = true
  this.message = 'Заполните все поля'
}
```

А, ну и для того чтобы было понятнее откуда берестя upFiles

```
 addFile() {      
        for (var i = 0; i < this.$refs.file.files.length; i++) {
          this.url.push(URL.createObjectURL(this.$refs.file.files[i]))
          this.claim.upFiles.push(this.$refs.file.files[i])
        }
      }
```